# Custom DDR controller initialization in u-boot code

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, u-boot, imx6, bsp

I am working on custom board 
part of that, we are changing DDR controller presented in the Board imx6ull board
Question
1. what are all changes to make new DDR controller up
2. What are other controllers depend DDR controller in u-boot code.
3. What is meant by DDR calibration in SoC 
4. What is DDR controller IC name used in existing board

I have gone through u-boot code,
DDR init is present with .c file as 
spl_ddr_init() --> mx6ul_dram_iocfg() & mx6_dram_cfg()

Board name: imx6ul_14x14_evk board

Can you please provide information with doc.s/links to understand the same.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Satish G

Answer (score 0):

First point to make clear is the imx6 has an internal DDR controller. The DCD commands in the various imx6 boards may or may not be suitable for your custom board. Likely, your board designer did not stray too far from the beaten path with with how they routed the traces and with the DDR chips they used. You will need to look at the board schematic to figure out what board and settings are closest to your custom board. With luck you can tweak and already existing u-boot board profile to match your custom board. From there you can boot up and see if you are able to access your DDR. There are also imx6 spreadsheets that are on the NXP website that you can use to provide you with a set of DDR configuration commands https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-333791. The imx processors generally boot with .imx image that contains these DCD commands at the start of the image to configure your DDR controller for you. The u-boot mkimage tool is what places these commands where they need to be. An example is under board/mx6ullevk/imximage.cfg. This contains all of your DDR controller commands and is used by mkimage to put this data at the start of your .imx image. If you are able to get u-boot running and you are able at least access your DDR, you can then run a tool https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-333791 that can help to fine tune the parameters configuring your DDR controller in combination with the unique characteristics of your hardware for good stability and performance. With luck, you will get well performing DDR without becoming an expert. If your board designer is too far off the beaten, path you you will need to use a DDR analyzer scope to and become quite an expert in high speed digital logic.